# Can't see wifi networks on laptop

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

On the login screen in Windows 10, I click on the wifi icon and a list of networks appear, everything is fine and I can connect to it normally.

But as soon as I log in the user account, I click on the wifi icon and no list appears, no network appears. I did a reset in the network control panel, I also used the netsh int ip command and the netsh winsock command as well just in case and that didn't do anything.

I even went further and did something drastic or extreme as in update the windows 10 on top of it. In other words, I inserted the USB windows 10 install and installed it on top of it. so I did a refresh in other words. still nothing.

so wifi works. I don't need to open the laptop and do some diagnostic under the hood. I know its something about Windows

Anyone have clues ?

Comment: Yes, we all have clues. :-) Is this computer on a network that could be running a login script?

Comment: Not at all. No script. Its not on a domain.

Comment: I also check with adwcleaner to be sure that its cleaned and found nothing

Comment: If you use another user account on the laptop doe sit work? If so, possible your regular profile is corrupted.